# environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() shows path which doesn't even exist

Tags: android

When I print the SD Storage path using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();`, it returns `storage/emulated/0`
but when I use DDMS to browse SD Storage there is no such directory at all. The available directory is `storage/emulated/legacy`

Why `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();` shows path which doesn't even exist ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path exists for your app's process.

Android, starting with 4.2, supports multiple accounts per device (originally just for tablets, now for all devices starting with 5.0). Each account gets its own distinct area for internal and external storage. The framework will return paths from methods like `getExternalStorageDirectory()` that are correct for the current account holder that is running your app. What these locations map to in terms of actual filesystem locations is up to Android, as part of its effort to secure access to storage.

Comment: so which path am I suppose to list all files ?

Comment: and how those `File Explorer` apps works when the path is different for all vendors :S ?

Comment: @Joe: I do not understand your question. Android apps use methods like `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` and `getExternalStorageDirectory()` (both on `Environment`), plus `getExternalFilesDir()` and `getExternalCacheDir()` (both on `Context`), to access specific locations on external storage. The actual directories returned by these methods will work, but they may vary (hence, do not hard-code them) and they may not directly match what you see in DDMS.

Comment: @Joe: "File explorer" apps show *the current user's files*, by means of methods like `getExternalStorageDirectory()`. File explorers that run on rooted devices and therefore can use things like **`su`** can hack their way around this to show files everywhere.

Comment: +1000 for wonderful explanation...just one question, how do you know so much about Android platforms ? i see a lot of answers by you here ? Any book recommendation ?. Sorry, i am just curious

Comment: @Joe: "how do you know so much about Android platforms ?" -- I have been showing people how to write Android apps for 6.5 years. "Any book recommendation ?" -- well, I like [my book](https://commonsware.com/Android). :-)

Comment: Where to buy your book ?, Amazon link on your website is dead, http://www.amazon.com/Android-Maps-V2-Development-Coders-ebook/dp/B00I0HUCD0/ref=sr_1_3

Comment: @Joe: It is available digitally via [the Warescription](https://commonsware.com/warescription). I have replaced the link to the excerpt on Amazon to [a downloadable PDF excerpt](https://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt-6p3.pdf).

Comment: In my case I am using the path provided by this method in my shell script that I run as root... and it obviously fails. Suggestions? :(

Comment: @KamranAhmed: No, because I have never dealt with root.

Comment: @CommonsWare Got my answer, there is an environment variable that holds the path to external sdcard... `$EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, it can be used in Java as `System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE")` while compiling dynamic shell script or for whatever reason. Thanks.